# Converting VB.NET to C# what are these Data Types?

Tags: c#, vb.net, object

I'm not too familiar with Visual Basic. I've been trying to figure out what kind of Data Types these are below:

I thought the type (below) was a boolean array but when I scanned down the code to see its use, it seems like it is serving as an object of some sort (see 2nd image).

```
Public MixedGas(1) As Boolean
```

Also, any help on how I can create the statement for

```
Public MolFrac(0 to 30, 0 To 30) As Single
```

I'm assuming this is a `int[,]` type?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your first instinct was right. Those are VB's array declaration and array indexing syntaxes. It uses `()` instead of `[]`. I believe the upper bound is inclusive so `(1)` actually has two elements, but often it's ignored/unused as if it's exclusive.

Comment: @madreflection how would I declare the "MixedGas" type in C#?

Comment: I believe it would be `public bool[] MixedGas = new bool[2];`

Comment: `MixedGas` is not a type, it's a field. VB uses the opposite order. Its type is `bool[]`.

Comment: Ah ok I think I get it now.

Comment: you probably mean `public float[,] MolFrac = new float[31, 31];`

Comment: As for `MolFrac`, you're close. It's `float[,]`, so `public float[,] MolFrac = new float[31, 31];`.

Comment: Upper bound is inclusive, but the lower bound is not necessarily 0.